Compact abelian groups with finitely many connected components
I want to look at the structure of compact abelian groups with finite number of connected components. For now, let us look at groups with exactly 2 connected components. If we let $G_0$ be the identity component, then the two components are two homeomorphic copies of $G_0$. Thus I believe $G/G_0\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and hence we have a short exact sequence $$1\to G_0\to G\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 1$$ I am concerned whether this splits or not (topologically). I really can't come up with examples that are not split.
More generally, if we have $n$ components, I believe we have $$1\to G_0\to G\to F\to 1$$ where $|F|=n$. Can we put some topological conditions on $G$ to make this split?
I may be completely off the rails here honestly (since I am trying to come up with these concepts almost on my own), so I would like  some feedback on what is really going on here.

You are right to believe the existence of the sequence $$0 \rightarrow G_0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$$ when $G$ is abelian. Indeed, $G$ acts transitively on its connected components, and the set of elements that preserves $G_0$ is exactly $G_0$. It is a normal subgroup, as $G$ is abelian. Thus $G/G_0$ is a group, along with a simple and transitive action on the connected components. 

The sequence may or may not split. For example, consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ along with the topology of open subsets $(\{ \overline{0},\overline{2}\}, \{ \overline{1}, \overline{3} \})$. It is a topological group and the connected component of the identity is $\{\overline{0}, \overline{2} \} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. 
Hence we have an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \underset{G_0}{\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}} \rightarrow \underset{G}{\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0,$$
which does not split. 
More generally, if $G$ is a group and $G_0$ a normal subgroup, we have a topology making $G$ a topological goup and $G_0$ the connected component of the identity. The sequence then splits if and only if $G$ is a product of $G_0$ by an other subgroup.

This was exactly the example I had in mind that was causing me doubts. Thank you for confirming it! As for your last statement, that is indeed what it is. Can we gurantee some topological condition when the sequence splits? Or is it hopeless to ask such a question?

Unfortunately, I have no idea if there exist some good condition that makes the sequence splits, but it might exist. I only thought about Lie groups : abelian Lie groups are of the form $\mathbb{R}^d \times (S^1)^r$, rhus a compact abelian Lie group is of the form $(S^1)^r$. Then the sequence does split.

Yes! I knew the condition for Lie groups, and in fact that gives me hope that something can be found. Lie groups restrict too much, we only have torii. But let's see if someone can come up with something. Thanks!

@EnguerrandMoulinier: Surely that classification of compact Abelian Lie groups assumes connectedness, though?  I don’t have any non-split examples, but there are at least the obvious split ones of the form $(S^1)^r \times G$ for any (discrete) finite group $G$.

Indeed it is an error I made. I wanted to edit but I will do it later. Once you have the classification for connected compact abelian Lie group, if $G$ is a compact abelian Lie group, then we have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow G_0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$, with $F$ finite. By the classification of compact abelian Lie group, $G_0$ is divisible. Thus $H^2(G_0,F)=0$, hence the sequence splits.
